# Geometric Shapes that can be placed inside itself

Tags: geometry

My questions title may need to be improved, and I am highly open for recommendations. Also if this is the incorrect community to post in, I would be happy to be directed to the correct one.

I am looking for a concept, and then recommendations. What I want is shapes that can fit within themselves by using a larger number of the same shapes. I should note there can be no remaining space in the original shape, and the smaller shapes have to be the same (just scaled down). I should also note that all smaller shapes need to be equal in size to each other (e.g. cannot use multiple sized shapes to fill the area).

For instance, a square can be cut into four equal sized squares, which make up the area of the square.

Also, a triangle can be cut into 4 equal sized triangles which will fit into the original triangle.

Is there any other, more complex, shapes that have this property? Also if this property has a specific name I would love to know it - as searching yields no results because I am uncertain what to look for.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for fractals, or self-similar sets.

Comment: This strikes me as a special case in problems of tiling the plane.  If a shape can tile itself, in can certainly tile the plane.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word you are looking for is [rep-tile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - however I am rather sad to see that only the few shapes I was able to come up with offhand are the majority of the examples. Thanks for this!